# How to create a custom Textbox with a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I want to create a custom control(or user control) which has both a textblock and a textbox as in the fig below:

[image]

Both the textblock and Textbox text properties are to be bound to the database fields and be able to apply styling etc. Which is the best approach for the same?

I have come up with a solution as below:

XAML for user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestDependency.TextBlox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         x:Name="abc"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
<Grid Width="170">
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" 
               Text="{Binding Path=Caption}"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" />
    <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,-2,0,0" 
             x:Name="TextBox1"
             Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind for Usercontrol:

```
public  partial class TextBlox : UserControl
{
    public  TextBlox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(TextBlox));
    public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(TextBlox));


    public string Caption
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    static void ValueChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        TextBlox inst = (TextBlox)property;
        inst.TextBox1.Text = (string)args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

XAML for actual form where Usercontrol is used:

```
 <Grid x:Name="grdmain">
    <my:TextBlox Caption="{Binding XValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{Binding WindowName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,197,0,0"  x:Name="textBlox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataEntities dt = new DataEntities();
    CoOrdinate oCord;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        oCord = dt.CoOrdinates.First();
        grdmain.DataContext = oCord;
    }
}
```

Still the binding doesnt work. But the code :

```
textBlox1.Caption = "test";
```

is working fine. where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an user control with a textblock and textbox and bind the values to that control.

```
<YourUserControl TextBlockText="{Binding TextBlockText}" TextBoxText="{Binding TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Looks like the basic idea but I don't think that Binding is complete.

Comment: That's right, but I don't know if Sony has a ViewModel or not or how he get his values

Comment: You just need to make the binding 2way, for the TextBox